# Playing a video in android using unity3d

Tags: android, c++, unity-game-engine, video

How can I play a mp4 video file for Android in Unity? 
I know there is a Movie Texture for PC, but how do I play videos in Android?

Answer (score 2):

Movie textures are not supported in android. You have to use [Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie.html)

so your function will be something like

```
function Start () {
        Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie ("yourfile.mp4", Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.CancelOnInput);
    }
```

Comment: useful link: https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-3-extension-technical-discussion/video-playback-issue-unityandroid